# Override MSP Recaptcha module view

Tags: magento2

I want to override **MSP_ReCaptcha** module to change the view and add some messages, I already tried this but no clue :

```
ap/design/frontend/company/theme/MSP_ReCaptcha/view/frontend/templates/msp_recaptcha.phtml
```

But this is not working, did I miss something?

The actual package is : `vendor/msp/recaptcha/view/frontend/templates/msp_recaptcha.phtml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

> app/design/frontend/company/theme/MSP_ReCaptcha/view/frontend/templates/msp_recaptcha.phtml

to

> app/design/frontend/company/theme/MSP_ReCaptcha/templates/msp_recaptcha.phtml

Comment: That did the trick thanks you very much!